# BackUp Dockerized PostreSQL Database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I have a docker-compose based Postgresql container, together with Pgadmin

I want to make a backup for my database to prevent data loss.
So I thought to create the backup from the Pgadmin interface, but this would create a backup file inside the container itself.

What I tried to figure out is,
how I can create a backup in case of running by mistake docker-compose down? which will erase all the volumes that are attached to the docker-compose file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a folder inside the container to a host folder and use pgadmin to create a backup that will be persisted outside the container (`docker-compose down` has no effect on it):

```
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - /folder/in/host:/folder/in/container
```

For example: If you create a backupfile say in `/folder/in/container/pg.dump`, it will also be available on the host as `/folder/in/host/pg.dump`

---

Or you can create a volume with `docker volume create --name somename` that will be stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` that even `docker-compose down -v` will not remove:

```
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - somename:/folder/in/container

volumes:
  somename:
    external: true
```

More about volumes:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: This locals mounting of the volume worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, for production use, you don't use `docker-compose` but docker swarm or kubernetes. **docker-compose is made for testing** and you should not manage your production or even a equivalent test system that must have SLA (like no data loss) using docker-compose.

Then docker-compose down do not remove the volumes, to do that, you would need to add the "-v" option like:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Third if you want to use a persistant volume not managed by the docker-compose but that is long lived, declare it as **external**, as per the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/):

> Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images
> created by up.
>
> By default, the only things removed are:
>
> Containers for services defined in the Compose file Networks defined
> in the networks section of the Compose file
> The default network, if one is used
> **Networks and volumes defined as external are never removed.**

This way you decouple you volume lifecycle from your containers. The documentation on volumes also explains how you can use volume drivers to get access to distant file systems and backup volumes if necessary: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

So if you want backup, do that by a shell command to a specific folder mapped to a volume that is potentially behind the scene a distant file system and is itself considered safe (backuped & replicated).

Comment: Thanks, that totally means that I misunderstood the -v param. I found the mounting of the volume incorrect from my side, this is why also my data used to be lost every docker-compose down.